# URL error char set?

Tags: ios, swift, url, web-applications

I tried to call a custom url using this code below:

```
let myurl = "https://myserver.com/call?a|b|c"
let converted = URL(string: myurl)
print(converted)
```

But what I'm getting as result in `converted` is just `"nil"`.

---

I'm pretty sure this is because of the **wrong characters set** in relation to the `URL()` class.

After some research all I got so far is this outdated Swift code:

```
var myurl = "https://myserver.com/call?a|b|c"
var newurl = myurl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
print(newurl)
```

But it doesn't seems working this way.

How can I achieve to avoid the "nil" result using (*in my case*) Swift 4?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on my own:

```
let myurl = "https://myserver.com/call?a|b|c"
let converted = URL(string: myurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)

print(converted!)
```

The new function is called `addingPercentEncoding` & I have to call it with the `urlQueryAllowed` property.

The **urlQueryAllowed** charset adds some characters like this to the url encoding: "`!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]|`"

Volià!